# In Gmail, how to find messages that are in the 'All Mail' folder, but nowhere else?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

In Gmail, how does one determine which email messages are in `All Mail`, but nowhere else?

I'm referring to email messages that are not in the `Inbox` (or another folder) and do not have any labels assigned.

Comment: Use `in:archive`

Answer (score -2):

In Apple Mail (served by Gmail) you can create a Smart Mailbox with these conditions.